# Calculating things inside a circuit with resistors (parrallel and series)

Tags: resistors

I have gotten the flowing practice exercises that I need to do:
[image: The exercises]

I have done 3 and 4, but I don't understand exercise 5. I have calculated the amperage that goes trough R1 (I think):

R1 = 50 Ohm so the remaining is 65 Ohm

R1 can let a maximum of 230/65 = 3,5384 A flow, so there is an amperage of 3,5384 - 2,0 = 1,538 A flowing to the rest of the circuit (if I am right).

Then I am stuck. The formula of the resistance in parallel is 1/Rt = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 and so on. but I don't see how you can calculate the amperage flowing trough R2.

I am very keen to learn the basics of resistance, and it would be great if somebody could help me out.

Comment: I cant understand the language mentioned in the picture...translate to English please

Comment: @Aadarsh I all ready translated the information needed to answer my question. R1 = R2 = R3 = 50 Ohms and R5 = R6 = 25 Ohms. That's all you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current division. Once you calculate current flowing through resistor 1, you need calculate how the current is split among resistor 2, 3 and 4.

They all share the same voltage drop, but not the same current.

**Current Division Formula**
$$ I_x = \frac{R_{total}}{R_x} * I_{In}$$

**Case:** Current divison among three resistors in parallel. 
$$ R_{Total} = R2 || R3 || R4 = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + \frac{1}{R_4}} = 15$$
$$ R_x = R_2 $$
$$ I_{R2} = \frac{R_{total}}{R_2} * I_{In}$$
$$ I_{R2} = \frac{15}{50} * 2.0A$$

Comment: I don't think we need to take the voltage drops into account, however I quite fancy to learn it. Could you explain the formulas in more detail please? So how do you calculate the voltage drops and how to you calculate the current that is going to pass trough the total circuit? Rtotal equals the replacement resistance of R2, R3 and R4 right?

Comment: Right, notice in this answer for this approach you don't need to calculate the voltage. I was simply iterating the current situation that the current is split while the voltage equivalent across all resistors.

Comment: So you are basically calculating how much the amperage scales down relative to the 50 Ohms of R1?

Comment: Mathematically speaking, yes. I would say how much the current is distributed, no current is lost, it's simply distributed across all three components(R2, R3, R4). The more resistance, the less current, and vice versa. An analogy can be a river with three paths, and the resistances is the quantity of boulders. The path with less boulders will have higher water flow rate (or current flow), than the path with less.

Comment: Aha, I think I am getting it right, now. So there will be flowing 0,6 amps each trough R2 and R3 and 0,8 amps flowing trough R4?

Comment: Right, and the sum of these currents add up to the total of current flowing through this circuit

Comment: And if R3 was different than R2? I need to do the samething for IR3 as described in your answer? So the 'general formula' is 
IR.no = R.no /R1 * 2.0A?

Comment: The first equation is the general formula. If you only change R3, then only R_Total changes, and obviously the current flowing through R_2 will change, however the rest of the equations remain the same.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I see the formula I was searching for now!

Answer (score 0):

The total current of your circuit is already known, it's 2A. This leaves you with a voltage over R2,3,4 of:

```
(15 Ohm)*(2 A) = 30V
```

Finally, the amperage through R2 is found as:

```
(30 V)/(50 Ohm) = 0.6A
```

Comment: Is this still the case when the voltage is also known? This is the case here and the voltage is 230V.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest the resistance, the larger the current that is flowing through it. You are right in thinking that since R1 has 3.5384 A flowing through it, so must all other elements in series. From this, you know that I going through R5 is 3.5384 A and I going through R6 is also 3.5384 A. What about the parallel sequence? 3.5384 A is split between all three resistors. Recall that the smaller the resistance, the larger the current. Therefore, there is an inverse relationship to the resistance on each resistor. This is the reasoning behind a rule known as current divider rule, which is the current through any branch in a network of parallel resistors is I*(Rt/Rn). You can use current divider rule to solve this. In = (3.5384)*(Rt/Rn), where n corresponds to any of the resistors in the network.

Comment: R5 and R6 have different resistance values namely 25 Ohm. So basically, the electricity is flowing trough the resistor with highest conductivity (therefore the lowest resistance) which is R4 in this case, but isn't there any electricity flowing trough R2 and R3 then?

Comment: When the current is divided like in r2/r3/r, the current through each resistor is proportional to the resistors conductivty, or invers proportional to the resistance, so if it is divided between two resistors, one resistor ten time as resistant as the others, the one with the lowest resistance gets a ten time as high current as the one with the higher resitance.